# IdentityServer4 Introspection Endpoint API uses invalid hashing algorithm

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Trying to validate a token using Introspection Endpoint on IdentityServer4. I keep getting a 401:Unauthorized. My log looks like this:

```
dbug: IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore[0]
      Found MyAPI API resource in database
info: IdentityServer4.Validation.HashedSharedSecretValidator[0]
      Secret: MyAPI API uses invalid hashing algorithm.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretValidator[0]
      Secret validators could not validate secret
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ApiSecretValidator[0]
      API validation failed.
fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint[0]
      API unauthorized to call introspection endpoint. aborting.
```

My API is configured like so:

```
new ApiResource
                {
                    Name = "MyAPI",
                    DisplayName = "My API",
                    ApiSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("TopSecret".Sha256())
                    },
                }
```

I'm passing headers for content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded and authorization as Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx where x is my base64 encoded auth string (myapi:TopSecret). My Token is in the body of the post

What am I missing? Why am I getting "MyAPI API uses invalid hashing algorithm"? If it's invalid, what is a valid hashing algorithm?

Additional information: My resources are contained in a SQL db accessed via Entity Framework. Specifically, the setup is just the same as in the quickstart documentation found [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html). To get to the point I'm at I had to manually add my API to the ApiSecrets table and give it a Type (SharedSecret) and a Value, that being a Sha256 password.

In Startup.cs my COnfigureServices includes

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Configurations.Scopes.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Configurations.Clients.GetClients())

            .AddConfigurationStore(builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
                    options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
            .AddOperationalStore(builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, options =>
                    options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));

        // include the password validation routine
        services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, Configurations.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, Configurations.ProfileService>();

        services.AddMvc();
```

Under Configure:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ApiSecret = "TopSecret",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = false,

            ApiName = "MyAPI"
        });

        InitializeDatabase(app);

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseMvc();
```

Note that I added the ApiSecret, AutomaticAuthenticate and AutomaticChallenge to this section only after I started having the problem in an effort to make it work.

In my Scopes.cs I have the following API outlined:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "MyAPI",
                DisplayName = "My API",
                ApiSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("TopSecret".Sha256()),
                },

            }
        };            
    }
```

For Clients.cs:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
    {

        new Client
        {
            ClientName = "My Client",
            AlwaysSendClientClaims=true,                
            ClientId = "MyClient",
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("TopSecret".Sha256()) },
            RequireClientSecret=false,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser =true,
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
            AllowedScopes = { "MyAPI" },
            RequireConsent = false,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,

        },
```

That's more or less all there is to the code portion. The database that houses the configuration seems to be overriding any code changes I make though so I'm not sure how useful this all is. In the DB I created a record in the ApiSecrets table with an ApiResourceId of 1, added a description and expiration date, set the Type to "SharedSecret" and added the Secret using various formats including plain text, sha256 and base64.

Here's the full log during the call. Perhaps it will help. I see that there are some things about Bearer not being found or something like that but I'm not sure why that would be and if it affects the outcome of the procedure.

```
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 29.4277ms 401
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/connect/introspect application/x-www-form-urlencoded 762
info: IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.Infrastructure.NopAuthenticationMiddleware[7]
      Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No token found.
dbug: IdentityServer4.CorsPolicyProvider[0]
      CORS request made for path: /connect/introspect from origin: chrome-extension://aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo but rejected because invalid CORS path
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[7]
      idsrv was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Request path /connect/introspect matched to endpoint type Introspection
dbug: IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter[0]
      Mapping found for endpoint: Introspection, creating handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint for /connect/introspect
dbug: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint[0]
      Starting introspection request.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser[0]
      Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser[0]
      Parser found secret: BasicAuthenticationSecretParser
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser[0]
      Secret id found: MyAPI
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__name_0='?' (Size = 200)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [apiResource].[Id], [apiResource].[Description], [apiResource].[DisplayName], [apiResource].[Enabled], [apiResource].[Name]
      FROM [ApiResources] AS [apiResource]
      WHERE [apiResource].[Name] = @__name_0
      ORDER BY [apiResource].[Id]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__name_0='?' (Size = 200)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a3].[Id], [a3].[ApiResourceId], [a3].[Type]
      FROM [ApiClaims] AS [a3]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT TOP(1) [apiResource].[Id]
          FROM [ApiResources] AS [apiResource]
          WHERE [apiResource].[Name] = @__name_0
          ORDER BY [apiResource].[Id]
      ) AS [apiResource2] ON [a3].[ApiResourceId] = [apiResource2].[Id]
      ORDER BY [apiResource2].[Id]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__name_0='?' (Size = 200)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a2].[Id], [a2].[ApiResourceId], [a2].[Description], [a2].[Expiration], [a2].[Type], [a2].[Value]
      FROM [ApiSecrets] AS [a2]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT TOP(1) [apiResource].[Id]
          FROM [ApiResources] AS [apiResource]
          WHERE [apiResource].[Name] = @__name_0
          ORDER BY [apiResource].[Id]
      ) AS [apiResource1] ON [a2].[ApiResourceId] = [apiResource1].[Id]
      ORDER BY [apiResource1].[Id]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__name_0='?' (Size = 200)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[ApiResourceId], [a].[Description], [a].[DisplayName], [a].[Emphasize], [a].[Name], [a].[Required], [a].[ShowInDiscoveryDocument]
      FROM [ApiScopes] AS [a]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT TOP(1) [apiResource].[Id]
          FROM [ApiResources] AS [apiResource]
          WHERE [apiResource].[Name] = @__name_0
          ORDER BY [apiResource].[Id]
      ) AS [apiResource0] ON [a].[ApiResourceId] = [apiResource0].[Id]
      ORDER BY [apiResource0].[Id], [a].[Id]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__name_0='?' (Size = 200)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a0].[Id], [a0].[ApiScopeId], [a0].[Type]
      FROM [ApiScopeClaims] AS [a0]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT [apiResource0].[Id], [a].[Id] AS [Id0]
          FROM [ApiScopes] AS [a]
          INNER JOIN (
              SELECT DISTINCT TOP(1) [apiResource].[Id]
              FROM [ApiResources] AS [apiResource]
              WHERE [apiResource].[Name] = @__name_0
              ORDER BY [apiResource].[Id]
          ) AS [apiResource0] ON [a].[ApiResourceId] = [apiResource0].[Id]
      ) AS [a1] ON [a0].[ApiScopeId] = [a1].[Id0]
      ORDER BY [a1].[Id], [a1].[Id0]
dbug: IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore[0]
      Found MyAPI API resource in database
info: IdentityServer4.Validation.HashedSharedSecretValidator[0]
      Secret: MyAPI Secret uses invalid hashing algorithm.
info: IdentityServer4.Validation.HashedSharedSecretValidator[0]
      Secret: MyAPI Secret uses invalid hashing algorithm.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretValidator[0]
      Secret validators could not validate secret
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ApiSecretValidator[0]
      API validation failed.
fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint[0]
      API unauthorized to call introspection endpoint. aborting.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 30.673ms 401
```

Comment: Maybe you can publish your whole VS solution so that will be easier for people to debug.

Comment: It's hard to tell but based on the code you posted it seems like that you are using your API and IdentityServer in one application. Could there be a mix up here?
Also why did you had to manually add a hashed ApiSecret? Did made a mistake there? 
If you followed the QS documentation `InitializeDatabase(app);` will only be populate your database if it contains no data, that might be the reason your code changes do not seem to take effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without seeing every little detail of the code and database configuration it is a bit hard. Also, I don't see the code where you actually make the call to the Introspection endpoint. Are you doing that in C# or in Javascript or with Postman?

Anyways, here's my review...

**Startup.cs**

The `ConfigureServices` method looks good. Adding a ResourceOwner password validator service is unnecessary for the stated problem; to access the Introspection endpoint an *ApiSecret* is needed, not a ResourceOwner password. I assume you have it there for some unrelated reason, if not, then take it out.

Under the Configure method you have `app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication` which means you are using the web app to not only act as the authentication server (using IdentityServer4), but it is also your Web Api application that calls back to the authentication server (itself in this case) to validate incoming tokens.

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://localhost:44388",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ApiName = "MyAPI"
    //ApiSecret = "TopSecret" not necessary to know the api secret for normal validation
    //AutomaticAuthenticate = true, not necessary
    //AutomaticChallenge = false not necessary
});
```

You also might want to `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()`.

**Api InMemory Configurations**

Using the `new ApiResource("name", "display")` constructor will setup the database correctly; but using the object initializer syntax as you did above won't. This is an issue reported to GitHub: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/836

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        // this will incorrectly leave out the ApiScope record in the database, but will create the ApiResoure and ApiSecret records
        new ApiResource
        {
            Name = "MyAPI",
            DisplayName = "My API",
            ApiSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("TopSecret".Sha256()),
            }
        },
        // this will correctly create the ApiResource, ApiScope, and ApiSecret records in the database.
        new ApiResource("MyAPI2", "My API2")
        {
            ApiSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("TopSecret2".Sha256())
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Fyi, since there are no Scopes specified in the `new ApiResources` directly above, the IdentityServer tooling will autogenerate one ApiScope for each ApiResource. The ApiScore gets the same name as the ApiResource in that case. An ApiResource must have at least one ApiScope; but could have many. It is the ApiScopes that are then related to the Client in ClientScopes table.

**Client InMemory Configuration**

See comments...

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientName = "My Client",
            AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
            ClientId = "MyClient",
            // changed the secret to make clear this is unrelated to the Api secret
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("TopSecretClientSecret".Sha256()) },
            // RequireClientSecret might as well be true if you are giving this client a secret
            RequireClientSecret = true,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
            // Added MyAPI2 from my example above
            AllowedScopes = { "MyAPI", "MyAPI2" },
            RequireConsent = false,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true
        }
    };
}
```

**Calling the Introspection Endpoint**

The following code is from a WebApi controller. (Remember, the IdentityServer authority and ApiResource are hosted in the same web application in this discussion). A request to this method would be made by a Client.

Inside this method you can see it calls to its authority's introspection endpoint to validate/decrypt the access_token. This is not necessary in this example because we setup up the web application to `app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication` which already does this. An introspection endpoint would be used for [Reference tokens](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/) or for when the web app is itself incapable of validating the access_token.

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class DataController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<String>> Secure()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var introspectionClient = new IntrospectionClient("https://localhost:44388/connect/introspect", "MyAPI", "TopSecret");

        var response = await introspectionClient.SendAsync(new IntrospectionRequest { Token = accessToken });

        var isActive = response.IsActive;
        var claims = response.Claims;

        return new[] { "secure1", "secure2", $"isActive: {isActive}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claims) };
    }
}
```

Here, using an `IntrospectionClient` for the ApiScope "MyAPI" would give a 401 because the database is missing the ApiScope due to the object initializer problem previously mentioned.

**One last thing**

Another possible issue is that manually adding a hashed ApiSecret in the database editor could result in weird copy/paste issues making the text unable to be decrypted properly.

**See full solution:**

https://github.com/travisjs/AspNetCore-IdentityServer-Instrospection

I hope this can help get to the bottom of the issue or at least stimulate a new thought.

Comment: This is the most concise answer so far. Unfortunately I can't load your solution because I'm relegated to using VS2015 for the moment and it appears your solution uses the new 2017 beta. That aside, I did manage to get some of your code to work. It appears I had the wrong approach, and to adapt your own phrase, you've stimulated some new thoughts on my part. Much appreciation, sir!

Comment: @Rafe yeah, I just rebuilt my machine and decided not to install VS 2015; if you dropped all the code into a VS 2015 project it should work- the project.json is the only real difference.

Comment: Thanks @travis.js. I'm awarding you the bounty on this. I was wondering though if it would be alright if I emailed you directly about a related problem I'm having on this project?

Comment: Sure, send me a line

Comment: Thanks Travis, I can't believe my problem was solved by your code with the comment "// this will correctly create the ApiResource, ApiScope, and ApiSecret records in the database." I think that's poor programming on the IdentityServer4 side.

Comment: A small question here: Why in the `IntrospectionClient` you don't do the hashing `"TopSecret".Sha256()`? Isn't it needed? How does the client know when to hash and with which hashing function? This is very confusing for me. I would expect it to work only if you hashed the secrets everywhere!

Comment: @user2173353 On the IdentityServer side they need to be hashed because (despite most examples are given in code) it is intended to read the config from a database or configuration file (where you do not want to store the secrets themselves). On the clients you need to use the original password (it will be hashed and then compared by IdentityServer).

Answer (score 0):

> (myapi:TopSecret). My Token is in the body of the post

The introspection endpoint needs a basic authentication that uses `scope:apisecret`, not `name:apisecret`.

Comment: I mis-typed that, it's actually MyAPI:TopSecret where MyAPI is the scope.